# How to add asp-for in javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript, asp.net, entity-framework

I am working with Asp.Net MVC, and I have a DTO that looks like this:

```
public class TaskDTO
{
    public string TaskName { get; set; }
    public string NextTaskName { get; set; }
    public bool IsBasicTask { get; set; }
    public int EstimatedTime { get; set; }
    public List<ResourceTaskDTO> RequiredResources { get; set; }
}

public class ResourceTaskDTO
{
    public string ResourceName { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

What I am trying to do, is that on the view side of this, I want to have forms and tables to fill up the TaskDTO. On the view side, I have the normal forms, and also a table that is populated by javascript to add the ResourceTaskDTO.

```
@model CMBuilder.Models.Api.TaskDTO

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Task</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="TaskName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="TaskName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="TaskName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="NextTaskName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="NextTaskName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="NextTaskName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="IsBasicTask" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsBasicTask)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="EstimatedTime" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="EstimatedTime" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="EstimatedTime" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="ResourceTable">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Resource Name</th>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Count</th>
                        <th><button type="button" name="add" id="btn_AddResource" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        i = 0;
        $("#btn_AddResource").click(function () {
            var html = '';
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<td><input type="text" asp-for="RequiredResources[i].ResourceName" class="form-control" /></td>';
            html += '<td><input type="text" asp-for="RequiredResources[i].Id" class="form-control" /></label></td>';
            html += '<td><input type="text" asp-for="RequiredResources[i].Count" class="form-control" /></td>';
            html += '<td></td></tr>';
            $('#ResourceTable').append(html);
            i++;
        });
    </script>
}
```

However, when I access the "RequiredResources" attribute in the ResourceTaskDTO in the controller's "Create" method, it is NULL and it seems that the javascript code did not hook into the "RequiredResources" attribute.

This is my Controller Code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("TaskName,NextTaskName,IsBasicTask,EstimatedTime,RequiredResources")] TaskDTO task)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            CMBuilderHandler Handler = new CMBuilderHandler(_service);
            var res = await Handler.CreateTask(task);

            if(res)
            {
                return Ok("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                return NotFound("Something went bad!");
            }
        }
        return View(task);
    }
```

What is wrong with my code? Why does task.RequiredResources null when I get it back on the controller?

Comment: `asp-for` will not be expanded, it will not evaluate, when added to the markup with client-side JavaScript. You will need to set the name attribute and values yourself for each form input.

Comment: If that's the case, what's the best way to implement what I am trying to do? I need a button that dynamically adds forms in a webpage, that creates asp-for to hook into the List of ResourceTaskDTO of my TaskDTO

Comment: You insert plain html without server-side evaluated tag helpers. If you want to take advantage of the tag helpers you'll need to use an AJAX request to render the partial view snippet on the server then attach it to your document after that response is returned.

Comment: I am still not 100% sure that I understand so correct me if I'm wrong, but I think what you are saying what I need to do is to not use the javascript code to append the html here, but when the btn_AddResource is clicked, create an AJAX POST request to insert the ResourceName, Id, and Count for the RequiredResourcesDTO, is that right?

Comment: Because you want dynamically generated form elements you need to use JavaScript. However, any html you add to the document will not be processed by the Razor engine therefore you cannot rely on tag helpers for this code. To help getting the correct html you can do a prototype view with a few "added rows" then peek at the generated html. That will help you to know how to craft correct markup without the tag helpers. The AJAX route is not _wrong_ but involves extra network requests but may have benefit if you require values from the server.

Comment: Here's an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46854686/2030565 that adds to the form.

Comment: Thanks so much for the link! I think I get it now, if you add the answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any new additions to the DOM with client-side JavaScript will not be processed by the Razor view engine so you cannot rely on server-side evaluated markup. Since `asp-for` is a Razor Tag Helper it will not be expanded.

You will need to set the *name* and *value* attributes yourself for each form input.

```
$("#btn_AddResource").click(function () {
    var html = '';
    ...

    html += '<td><input type="text" name="RequiredResources[' + i + '].ResourceName" value="" class="form-control" /></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="RequiredResources[' + i + '].Id" value="" class="form-control" /></label></td>';

    ...
    $('#ResourceTable').append(html);
    i++;
});
```

The name will need to match your models' properties to bind the values when submitted to the controller action.

Comment: after a long search, this solution become a shortcut for me, thanks mate!
how could not I think the name tag take place for binding a model property