# Dynamically adding form controls with JavaScript and proceessing the form in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm building a page where I need to add document templates. Each document will have unknown number of sections. The user will be able to give a name to the template and add as many sections as he wants. The section will have name and content. I have followed the example here:
[Create dynamic forms that grow at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46854085/create-dynamic-forms-that-grow-at-run-time)
However the collections with section is always empty. Here are my models, controller and some code from the view.

NewDocumentViewModel.cs

```
public class NewDocumentViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<SectionViewModel> Sections { get; set; }

        public NewDocumentViewModel()
        {
            this.Sections = new List<SectionViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

Here is the SectionViewMode.cs

```
public class SectionViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SectionName { get; set; }
        public string SectionContent { get; set; }
        public int Position { get; set; }
    }
```

Following the example from the link above I have created a View file called Section.cshtml with the follow content:

```
@model SectionViewModel
    <input type="text" asp-for="SectionName" class="sections" />
    <input type="text" asp-for="SectionContent" class="contents" />
```

Then in my View called SaveTemplate I have the following in the form:

```
 <form asp-controller="Templates" asp-action="SaveTemplate">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <p>
                <a id="addSection" class="btn btn-success">Add new section</a>
                @Html.EditorFor(f => f.Sections)
            </p>
            <div class="form-group" id="sectionContainer">

            </div>


            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add document</button>
        </form>
```

And here is the JavaScript that is adding a new section:

```
<script>
    var count = 1;

    $('body').on('click', '#addSection', function () {

        var i = $(".sections").length;
        var y = $(".contents").length;

        var structure = $('<div>' +
            'Section name:<br />' +
            '<input type = "text" name="Section[' + i + '].SectionName" class = "form-control sections" /><br />' +
            'Section content:<br />' +
            '<textarea name="Section[' + y + '].SectionContent" id = "editor' + count + '" class= "form-control contents" placeholder = "Description" ></textarea >' +
            '</div > ');
        $('#sectionContainer').append(structure);
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor' + count);
        count++;
    });
</script>
```

I don't have much code in the controller as I have just created added to see if I'll get all the data from

```
 the View when debugging:

[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult SaveTemplate(NewDocumentViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

What is the reason for the Section collection to be always empty and how to solve this?

Comment: Ok, after a couple of hours of looking into that, I have figured it out. In the JavaScript where I'm appending - the name of the fields is wrong. It should be matching the name of the property from the model. The name is Sections, but I have Section in the code above. Changing it to: `<input type = "text" name="Sections[' + i + '].SectionName" class = "form-control sections" /><br />`  fixed the issue.